# Edit function in R using substitute with string as argument

Tags: r, function, edit, substitution

I am trying to edit a function with the use of the `body` and `substitute` functions in R. I want to construct a new line for the function from a string and after that substitute it into the function.

I suppose that I need to convert the string to a certain class, which `substitute` can evaluate and feed into the function. But, I how can I do that?

Below is an example of what I want:

```
myFun <- function(x) {
    A1 <- 1
    A2 <- 10
    A1 <- x^2 + A2  # Line to be changed
    return(A1 + A2)
}

n <- 2
m <- 1
express_string <- paste0("A", n, " <- x^2 + A", m)

body(myFun)[[4]] <- substitute( express_string )  # This is the tricky part.
```

This is what I want the function to look like in the end:

```
myFun <- function(x) {
    A1 <- 1
    A2 <- 10
    A2 <- x^2 + A1  # New line
    return(A1 + A2)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `parse`:

```
body(myFun)[[4]] <- parse(text = express_string)[[1]]
```

Of course, it would be preferable to not create R command as strings. `bquote` can be helpful:

```
LHS <- as.name(paste0("A", n))
RHS <- as.name(paste0("A", m))

express <- bquote(.(LHS) <- x^2 + .(RHS))

body(myFun)[[4]] <- express
```

Comment: It worked perfectly with `parse`. I tried that earlier but did not realise that I needed the `[[1]]` in the end. Can you elaborate a bit on why it is preferable to use `bquote`?

Comment: @Christoffer `parse` is slow. Depending on the use case (who creates `express_string`) it could also be a huge security risk, because it would allow executing arbitrary code (including calls to `system`).

Answer (score 2):

We can parse the expression

```
body(myFun)[[4]] <- rlang::parse_expr(express_string)    
myFun
#function (x) 
#{
#    A1 <- 1
#    A2 <- 10
#    A2 <- x^2 + A1
#    return(A1 + A2)
#}
```